# How do I access a tableview's pan gesture?

Tags: swift, tableview, cell, swipe, uipangesturerecognizer

Right now I'm having some trouble making my tableview's cells swipe-able. I know tableview is a scrollview and it uses a pan gesture. but accessing that pan gesture is weird. I want to be able to grab the location translation from it and know what user's touch coordinates are. After that it's a cheese walk.

I have been trying to add another pan gesture but to no success. It looks like it only wants to have one running at a time.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the current index path and save it in variable.
After that add bellow code.
Add you get the

```
let cellRect = self.MyTableView.rectForRow(at: currentindexPath)
```

then user cellRect to get point that you need using

```
var cellMidPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(cellRect), CGRectGetMidY(cellRect))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a delegate method you can implement if you want the cell to show more buttons on a swipe:

```
tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt:)
```

You can also implement these three if you just want to swipe to delete (two are declared in the data source and one in the delegate):

```
tableView(_:editingStyleForRowAt:)
tableView(_:canEditRowAt:)
tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)
```

You can read more about it [in the documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)

If you want something custom you can subclass `UITableViewCell` and detect a swipe there.